# read PDF into browser with hosted website

Tags: php, pdf

This is my code :

```
    $filename = $data['cmr'];

    $realpath = str_replace('../', '', $filename);

    $path = str_replace('/', '\\', $realpath);

    //On affiche le document PDF à l'écran

    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $content;
}
else
{
    echo 'Vous ne possédez pas les droits pour accéder à cette page.';
}
```

My problem is : "Failed to load PDF file". My website is hosted on ovh.

I tried to do :

```
$content = file_get_contents($path);
    //header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
    //header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    //header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    //header('Pragma: public');
echo $path;
```

And the path is OK. Moreover, if I copy this path and I put it into the browser as url (after domain name), I get my PDF file. But, the aim would be to hide this path from user with a php file named like view.php.

I have to specify that this is working on local without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for making you losing wasting your time. The solution was that I didn't put the right paths.